# Добавления данных в одном представление с одной модели в другую

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Модель Service:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string TextEmail { get; set; }
public virtual IEnumerable<Order> Order { get; set; }
```

Модель Order:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
```

У меня в одном представление осуществляется вывод данных с таблицы "Service"
И добавления данных в таблицу "Order". 

Get:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Service(string id)
        {
    var model = await _context.Services
                    .Where(a => a.Url == id)
                    .Include(....)
                    .ThenInclude(....)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            return View(model); //@model в представление определено Service
```

Post:

```
[HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Order(Service service, Order order) 
    {
        _context.Add(new Order {
                        Name = service.Name,
                        TextEmail = "TestTextEmail",
                        ServiceId = service.Id,
                        RegistrationDate = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                        });
      .......
```

Так вот, у меня поля двух таблиц не совпадают само собой.
Как такое можно вообще реализовать?. 
 То на сколько знаю, можно передавать только одну модель. Если возможно, хотел бы сделать что-то наподобии автозаполнения. 
Еще не нравится, что в формах приходится прописывать `name` , вместо `v-for`. 
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете реализовать такое через ViewModels и через Automapper, и в core есть хорошая штука как "asp-for"